# Why is coord_flip() better than switching `x` and `y` arguments in aes() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning ggplot2 and found about the `coord_flip()` option.

However, I see that it gives exactly the same plot as if I simply switched the `x` and `y` arguments.

For example, using the `mpg` dataset contained in the same package:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = class, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
```

and

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = hwy, y = class)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

both give exactly the following plot:

[image]

Regarding `coord_flip()`, the documentation says:

1. "This is primarily useful for converting geoms and statistics which display y conditional on x, to x conditional on y";
2. "Very useful for creating boxplots, and other interval geoms in the horizontal instead of vertical position".

However I would say that these two sentences say what `coord_flip()` does, not why it is useful to have this function instead of defining manually what the `x` and `y` are - as in any other plot.

Might it be purely for a reason of style/consistency in one's code, e.g. in terms of what is defined as `x` and what is defined as `y`?

Comment: It's a [new feature](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features) in ggplot2 v3.3.0 (4th bullet), but when they introduce new features they don't necessarily break the features they supersede. Most likely, `coord_flip()` is still around so that people's old code doesn't break. Most directional layers have gained an 'orientation' parameter. Perhaps the documentation of `coord_flip()` might benefit from an update.